# Apply multiple filters to a table in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a vehicles table. In my vehicles search page, I filter the vehicles according to models, colors etc selected.

In my code I tried to instantiate the vehicle model. Then applied the filters to it and tried to run query using get(), but feeds me with errors.

Code here:

```
    $vehicles = Vehicle::all();
    if($request->input('model'))
    {
        $vehicles->whereHas('model', function($q)
        {
            $q->where('model_name', '=', 'CL');

        });

    }
    if($request->input('color'))
    {
        $vehicles->where('color', '=', 'red');
    }
    // other filters here
    $result = $vehicles->get();
    dd($result);
```

Here a single filter works if I directly use whereHas on the Vehicle model like Vehicle::whereHas(). What is the solution if I had to apply multiple filters based on conditions. 
Who saves my day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So all you would need to do essentially is to have a `$conditions` array that has your filters, such as:

```
$conditions = collect([]);
$conditions->push($request->only(['model_name', 'color', 'year', 'valueMin', 'valueMax']'));
```

This will make a `collection` that contains only the `key => value` pairs from your `model, color, year, valueMin` and `valueMax` properties (maybe from some form?)

Then you'd simply pass that collection over to your query, like so:

```
Vehicle::where(function($q) use ($conditions){
    if ($conditions->has('color')) {
        $q->where('color', $conditions->get('color'));
    }

    return $q;
})->whereHas('model', function($q) use ($conditions) {
    return $q->where($conditions->toArray());
})->get();
```

This way you don't need to worry about hard coding your conditions in your query and you can have a never ending limit. You simply need to pass in an array with key value pairs when making direct comparisons.

This solution will allow for the dynamic property comparisons that you're looking for.

Comment: The model name is in models table which can be filtered using wherehas, but color is in vehicles table. I need to apply these based on if input present. There may be multiple whereHas to be applied too based on arriving inputs.

Comment: @mirzavu Updated to support further `where` filtering on parent table, and allowing `whereHas` on related tables.

Comment: The query worked now and I have suggested an edit for the collect to make it work! Please accept the edit and will mark this as ans. Thanks so much

Comment: @mirzavu I unfortunately don't see it on mobile, but I'll check my desktop when I'm back working and apply your edit. Glad it helped get you sorted!

Comment: No Issues. Learned more things now. Can you look into this for me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168103/laravel-5-eloquent-group-by-hasmanythrough-relationship-column

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
 $vehicles = new Vehicle();
        if($request->input('model'))
        {
           $vehicles =  $vehicles->whereHas('model', function($q)
            {
                $q->where('model_name', '=', 'CL');

            });

        }
        if($request->input('color'))
        {
           $vehicles = $vehicles->where('color', '=', 'red');
        }
        // other filters here
        $result = $vehicles->get();
        dd($result);
```

Comment: This works!!  but @Ohgodwhy has an advanced version of the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think `$vehicles = Vehicle::all();` is the best way to load data first and apply the filter then. This could have impact on performance in case of large number of records since you are loading all the data from the table including unnecessary records.

Try below for multiple condition:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::where(['model_name'=>'CL','color'=>'red'])->get(); //color is just an assumption. This way you can use multiple conditions.
dd($vehicles);
```

I hope this contributes something..

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes there will always be a model name and there will always be a color. What happens when there isn't?

Comment: In that case we can use the `QueryBuilder` if there are lot of if and else in the condition.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thats is fine, we can create the array based on existing parameters into the where(). But this works only when the model_name and color are columns of vehicle table. what if model_name is in a table models and color in table vehicles?

Comment: Yes we can do that